# matplotlib date as data, becoming gebrish

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some date in **matplotlib**:

```
plt.ylabel("Word Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Date")

x_values = [datetime.datetime.strptime(key,"%Y-%m-%d").date() for key in final]
y_values = [9,2,9,4,5,6,7,8,9]

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.plot(x_values,y_values)

plt.show()
```

This code is quite simple, but the result is seriously odd-looking:

[image: matplotlib date on axis, cause gebrish data]

When I did a `print(x_values)`, I got :

```
[datetime.date(2021, 4, 28), datetime.date(2021, 4, 20), datetime.date(2021, 5, 8), datetime.date(2021, 4, 29), datetime.date(2021, 4, 14), datetime.date(2021, 5, 11), datetime.date(2021, 5, 4), datetime.date(2021, 4, 26), datetime.date(2021, 5, 2)]
```

And these values don't even reassemble the values plotted.

Comment: The line segments are connected in the order they appear. You need to sort the x.values to get a nice graph. Or create a scatter plot.

Comment: @JohanC scatter is supposed to plot only, points... but there is something wrong with these data, please check this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8dgz.png

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad  You didn't ask for a scatter plot.  You asked for a line plot.  Cut-and-paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly un-sorted list was the problem:

```
x_values = [datetime.datetime.strptime(key,"%Y-%m-%d").date() for key in final]
x_values.sort()
y_values = [9,2,9,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```